# Multiple dynamic maps in same page using maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a system where I keep my addresses, I have a loop and the return of all of them where I loop the script passing the id of the div and address for each one, it works, however it does not render correctly all maps. Can someone help me?

http://quax.com.br/clientes/silvaesilva/escritorio

---

**I did and ended up with iframes going right, pass the parameter address that desire and renderizo in an iframe. Thank you.**